# MPEG DASH:using Gpac to get MPD files

Tags: linux, open-source, cross-platform, media

My goal is to convert some mpeg4 files in my hard disk into mpd files that will alllow me to use it in mpeg dash streaming .i read about gpac's MP4Box capability to create mpd files and i followed the instructions of the following link to successfully compile gpac for ubuntu like in the instructions in this two links

http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/2011/04/20/compiling-gpac-on-ubuntu/

http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/2012/02/01/dash-support/

But when i try to execute any command such as

```
  MP4Box -dash 10000 -frag 1000 -rap myFile.mp4
```

I get the following error

```
 Option -dash unknown. Please check usage
```

I wonder is there any commands or instructions that i must execute when building gpac to add the dash and if is there any other methods to get my own MPD File not those provided by itec.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow the compile instruction carefully & make sure to fetch the latest version from SVN.

MP4Box should work with your commands.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are using a outdated version of MP4Box. try downloading and compiling the latest one from here (for me the same command works): http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/